# Implement custom events in Google Tag Manager when I don't have access to the Tag Manager site

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm building a site for a client who uses Google Tag Manager,  they have sent me the javascript snippet to include on every page.
Now they are asking me to create custom events for certain user interactions.

My understanding is that I need to define these events within the Tag Manager Site  first. Is that correct?
But, How can I do this if I don't have access to the client's Tag Manager account?

Using Google Analytics (GA) I could just call ga() function in JS,  with the event name and parameters as arguments. I didn't need access to the GA management site itself.

Comment: This isn't related to coding so it's off topic, but to comment, you would need access to their GTM account to create the events. The problem with using the `ga` function is that it requires you to know the name of the tracker; you can't just go `ga('send', 'event', ...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect they are talking about [datalayer events](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#events), i.e. they want you to push a variable with the key "event" to the dataLayer after user interactions:

```
<div onclick="dataLayer.push('event':'divClicked')">Click Div</div>
```

Then they can use that to construct triggers inside GTMs that allows them to fire tags. The requirement would still be "create a custom event", since "event" might refer to a javascript event, a GTM event or Google event tracking, and without context these three might indiscernible ("I use an event to push an event that triggers an event"....).

"Custom Events" in GTM are events that are not automatically picked up (like pageload, DOM ready, click, submit etc).

Answer (score 0):

In case they use Google Tag Manager it is better to set up events in Google Tag Manager. 
You can create your own Google tag Manager container (test one) and set up all necessary tags and triggers for their website in there. You can test those tags via Tag Manager Injector Chrome extension and then give your client an export file.

Comment: give more detail what you are asking and you have tried